# Handling many static bodies in Processing

Tags: java, 3d, processing

I'm working on a Java program with Processing library, that plots/draws millions of galaxies (the coordinates do not change) in 3D-space (as simple points) and allows translating, rotating and scaling the view in real time.

I'm using Processing to have GPU acceleration on rendering the view, but the points have to be given to the graphics card by the CPU anyway. So currently my draw() method contains a for loop which "draws" the points one by one. Since nothing about the points changes, only the camera angle, position and scale, it is too slow for my needs.

Current draw():

```
transformSpace();
for (int i = 0; i < visibleBodies.length; i++) {
    Body b = visibleBodies[i];
    point(b.x, -b.z, -b.y); // Z-up world
}
```

Could all the points be handled somehow differently, so draw() wouldn't have to contain a massive loop? I've been unsuccessful in trying to find a way to feed the coordinates to the GPU in a separate one-time process or make all the data one big object.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw the to a `PGraphics` ahead of time, and then just draw that `PGraphics` when you want to draw your bodies.

```
PGraphics image;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  image = createGraphics(500, 500);

  image.beginDraw();
  for (int i = 0; i < visibleBodies.length; i++) {
    Body b = visibleBodies[i];
    image.point(b.x, -b.z, -b.y); // Z-up world
  }
  image.endDraw();

}

void draw() {
  background(255, 0, 0);
  image(image, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

More info can be found in [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/).

Comment: Is the PGraphics rotatable, scalable or translatable in 3D-space?

Comment: @GregorEesmaa Sure, you would just use the `texture()` function. Try looking at the Processing reference or googling something like "processing draw image in 3d" for a start. Feel free to post another question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck!

Comment: Would PGraphics in 3D behave as if the points were on their own or would I be transforming just the projection of the points on a 2D plane?

Comment: @GregorEesmaa I'm not sure I understand your question. It's going to depend on exactly what you do. Your question says your points are static, so I don't know what "behaving on their own" means in this context. The best thing you can do is try something out and post another question if you get stuck though.

Comment: Using PGraphics projects the 3D space I want to rotate, scale and translate to a 2D plane. To properly transform it, I would have to recreate the PGraphics image. While the coordinates of the bodies are static, the camera shouldn't be.

Comment: @GregorEesmaa If you want your camera to move between the bodies in 3D space, then those bodies are not static with regard to drawing them to the screen.

Comment: But they have static positions in their space. My question also describes what I want to do with them.